# Firebasae goOffline/goOnline for a push

Tags: javascript, database, firebase

I have an application that pushes data to firebase. However I am hitting the 100 concurrent users regularly. So I was wondering if it would be possible to go online before pushing and go offline after the push was successful.

Here is what I tried:

```
Firebase.goOnline();
myFirebaseRef.child("pushed-object").push(this.toJson(), function () {
    Firebase.goOffline();
});
```

However, I get an exception/warning in Chrome:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://myapp.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&s=stuff&ns=someMoreStuff' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

Any recommendations on that issue? (except for purchasing a pro plan - I run a non-commercial application).

Comment: I am not familiar with the JS API, but it sounds like you will need to have a callback or listener that validates the push was successful and then goes offline.

Comment: Why don't you simply use the [Firebase REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/) to do the same thing?

Comment: @dazza5000 Thanks, the second parameter of the push function is actually that callback. But for some reason it seems to be called to early.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen that is actually a nice idea. I wanted to add more functions in the future. These functions are easier to support using the JS library.

Comment: That error message is normal when the Firebase client establishes its initial connection to the backend. It should not cause an early callback. But you should definitely handle the `error` parameter of the completion callback, to see if the save failed for some reason: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-completion-callback

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your reply. So the message does not indicate an issue?